# How to detect specific keys on keyboard keypress?

Tags: swiftui, keypress

How to detect letter 'A' keypress in swiftUI? macOS.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Rectangle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onHover { Bool in
                    
                    func doSomething(event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent? {
                        guard !event.isARepeat else {
                            return nil
                        }
                        
                        print ("key code for letter 'A' is" + event.keyCode.description)
                        if event.keyCode == 10 {
                            print("Letter 'A' pressed")
                            
                            return nil
                        }
                        
                        return event
                    }
                    
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

P.S: To the person who will give negative votes for this question anyways --> it's a tradition in stackoverflow to give negative votes as much as possible. so, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code lets you type any key and display its character.
Adapt this to detect specific key pressed on the keyboard in macos.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var keyPressed: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(keyPressed)
            .onAppear {
                NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.keyDown]) { nsevent in
                    if let char = nsevent.characters {
                        keyPressed = char
                    }
                    return nsevent
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Do not declare functions, such as `func doSomething(event: NSEvent)` inside the `.onHover{...}`, it is not the appropriate place to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to detect "Shift" key etc which are not capturing from above code?

Comment: use `if nsevent.modifierFlags.contains(.shift) {...}` to detect if the `shift` key is also pressed.

Comment: I realised when Shift key is pressed, the raw data of `NSEvent` contains a `flag: 0x20102` is it a unique flag for shift key for any keyboard brand? I mean if I change the keyboard brand, will the new keyboard send the same flag or it will depend on the brand of the keyboard? I'm thinking of hard coding the flag to my software. For instance, if flag == 0x20102 { print ("shift")}. Will it likely to cause problems if I run it in a different keyboard brand?

Comment: I don't know about the effect of different keyboards brand.
 I would avoid hard coding anything. Why not use `NSEvent.ModifierFlags.shift`
 like in the example I showed you.

Comment: the example works for single button press, but how to detect multiple keypresses like `Shift + control + mouse left button click`. I saw `flags` and `data` uniquely change when I press multiple buttons that's why I was thinking to use the `flag`

Answer (score 0):

In swiftui 5 there is now an onKeyPress method, the code given by sumida in the above can then be replaced by the following

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var keyPressed: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(keyPressed)
            .onKeyPress { press in
                keyPressed = press.characters
                return .handled
            }
    }
}
```

[See apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onKeyPress(_:action:))